# sql regex to remove non xml characters

Tags: sql, xml, regex

I am looking for a SQL query which can remove all non-xml characters i.e. characters out of

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

from my rows.

I can use http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/ to create regex replace user defined function. But I am having a hard time writing a regex to locate the non-xml characters. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What exactly are non-xml characters? Can you point us to a page on the net? What does #x9 mean?

Comment: @buckley Hex `0x9`, or horizontal tab. `0xA` is new line, `0xD` is carriage return, and the others are ranges of acceptable characters. Asker wants to remove characters that are not among the ranges listed.

Comment: According to w3c recommendation only #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] 
 characters are allowed in xml, #x9 is hexadecimal 9 unicode character. Please check out http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFFF]
```

How did I come to that?

- In the .net regex engine you can encode Unicode characters as \uxxxx
- If you put ^ you create a negated character class meaning it will match everything that is not in that list (I'm assuming you want this but it was not 100% clear from your question)

If you replace these matches with the empty string you will filter out the "illegal" characters.